# How to clear tabs while navigating within tabbedpanle in wicket

Tags: wicket, tabpanel

I'm building a `tabbedpanel` which consists of three tabs. I have a tab with form with text fields in it. while I am navigating from this tab I'm unable to loose the state of this tab. Can anyone suggest how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Form/ around the TabbedPanel? If YES then you can override

```
org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.tabs.TabbedPanel#newLink()
```

And do something like:

```
form.setModelObject(new EmptyObject())
```

Or:

```
form.setModelObject(null)
```

Or:

```
use a visitor to set "empty"/null model for each FormComponent in the complete form
```

Or:

Just in the specific tab by using the passed `'index'` parameter to `#newLink()`.